# Store geolocation coordinates as a const variable react

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, constants

im a little stuck. Im trying to store the user coordinates from the componentDidMount in the handlesubmit as a const however whenever i try to I'll get an error. The error i'm getting is :
'position' is not defined  no-undef.
Any way i could go about storing the position as a const so i could access it in the handlesubmit part?

Thanks
Code is below

```
componentDidMount() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos ) {
        const { latitude, longitude } = pos.coords;
        console.log(pos )
        console.log(latitude)
        console.log(longitude)
      });
    }
    
    handleSubmit = (event) => {   

        const pName = document.querySelector('#pName') .value.trim();
        const pCondition = document.querySelector('#pCondition') .value.trim();
        const pDescription = document.querySelector('#pDescription') .value.trim();
        const pLocation = position
        console.log(pLocation )


        const post = 'pName=' + encodeURIComponent(pName) + '&pCondition=' + encodeURIComponent(pCondition) + '&pDescription=' + encodeURIComponent(pDescription);
        
        alert('A form was submitted: ' + data);
  
      fetch('api url', {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: "no-cors",
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
          
//          body: JSON.stringify(this.state)

           body: post
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.text)
          /*return response.json();*/
        });
  
      event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple

```
const getPosition = function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
  });
}

getPosition()
  .then(position => {
    console.log(position);
    sessionStorage.setItem('position', position);
  )
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

Use the variable position in the [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

```
const data = sessionStorage.getItem('position');
```

Or you can use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

Answer (score 0):

```
const getPosition = function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
  });
}

getPosition()
  .then(position => {
    console.log(position);
    sessionStorage.setItem('position', position);
  )
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

Comment: Hi, just tried implementing this and received this error :Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    at Form (http://localhost:3000/main.c3a16ae847d837f591f3.hot-update.js:26:5)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1

Comment: Added extra checks.